# Need help with numerical implementation of a model

Tags: corporate-finance, numerical-methods, matlab

I am toying around with a capital structure model that looks as follows:
$\sup_{D_{t}(A_{t}),K_{t}}\int_{B_{L}}^{B_{H}}(1-\kappa_{t})\pi(t,A_{t},K_{t},B_{t})g_{t}(B_{t})dB_{t}+\kappa_{t}D_{t}(A_{t})[1-G_{t}(B_{Th}(t,A_{t},K_{t},D_{t}(A_{t})))]\\-\int_{B_{L}}^{B_{Th}(t,A_{t},K_{t},D_{t}(A_{t}))}(1-\kappa_{t})(1-\theta_{t})\pi(t,A_{t},K_{t},B_{t})g_{t}(B_{t})dB_{t}$

where bankruptcy threshold $B_{Th}$ has to solve
$\pi(t,A_{t},B_{Th}(t,A_{t},K_{t},D_{t}(A_{t})))=\chi D_{t}(A_{t})$

The value of $\pi_t$ is given by:
$\pi_{t}(A_{t},B_{t},K_{t})=\frac{\left(A_{t}K_{t}^{\alpha}L_{t}^{\beta}\right)^{\frac{1+\sigma_{t}}{\sigma_{t}}}}{\left(R_{t}P_{t}^{\sigma_{t}-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma_{t}}}}-f_{t}K_{t}-\frac{w_{t}L_{t}}{B_{t}}$

and the value of $L_t$ is given by
$L_{t}=\left[\frac{w_{t}}{B_{t}}\frac{(R_{t}P_{t}^{\sigma_{t}-1})^{\frac{1}{\sigma_{t}}}}{(A_{t}K_{t}^{\alpha})^{\frac{1+\sigma_{t}}{\sigma_{t}}}}\frac{\sigma_{t}}{\beta(\sigma_{t}+1)}\right]^{\frac{\sigma_{t}}{\sigma_{t}+\beta(1+\sigma_{t})}}$

Finally $P_t$ is :
$P_{t}=\left[M\int_{A_{L}}^{A_{H}}\left[\int_{B_{L}}^{B_{H}}\frac{(A_{t}K_{t}^{\alpha})^{1+\frac{\sigma_{t}^{2}}{(1+\sigma_{t})(\sigma_{t}+\beta(1-\sigma_{t}))}}}{R_{t}^{1+\sigma_{t}+\beta(1-\sigma_{t})}}\frac{w_{t}}{B_{t}}\frac{\sigma_{t}}{\beta(\sigma_{t}+1)}g_{t}(B_{t})dB_{t}\right]h_{t}(A_{t})dA_{t}\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\sigma_{t}(2-\beta)+\beta}}$

I am trying to numerically implement this model in MATLAB, since there are no closed form solutions, but I haven't done numerical implementations before, so I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.